# Vector decomposition into a convex combination of two vectors with constraints on the sum of their elements

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the vector $\mathbb{v}$ of $n$ elements and a scalar $0<q<1$, 
how can I find the vectors $\mathbb{v}_1$ and $\mathbb{v}_2$ such that

$$ \mathbb{v} = q\, \mathbb{v}_1 + (1-q)\,\mathbb{v}_2 $$

subject to $\sum \mathbb{v}_{1i} = c_1$ and $\sum \mathbb{v}_{2i} = c_2$,

being $c_1$ and $c_2$ two given integer scalars ?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: Perhaps you stated the problem wrong (getting the conditions in the wrong order or getting what's "given" wrong). As stated this is clearly impossible, because it implies that $\sum v_j=qc_1+(1-q)c_2$, which may not be so.

Comment: I am a statistician, trying to implement a particular bootstrap method for finite population (Antal and Tillé 2011, p. 539) which requires the contraction of $\mathbb{v}_1$ and  $\mathbb{v}_2$ as specified. I don't know how to tackle the problem, any  suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec 1$ be a vector for which every element is $1$. We can write your constraints as:

$$\vec 1\cdot\vec v_1=c_1,\ \ \ \vec 1\cdot\vec v_2=c_2$$

It should be clear that these define a pair of parallel (hyper)planes. If $\vec v$ is to be written as a convex combination of a point from each plane (which is to say, it lies on a line segment connecting them), it must lie between them. This gives us a simple feasibility test (assume without loss of generality $c_2>c_1$).

$$\exists\ \vec v_1, \vec v_2\iff c_1\le\vec 1\cdot\vec v\le c_2$$

To actually find $v_1$ and $v_2$, we can draw a line from $\vec v$ that intersects both planes. To do this, choose any $\vec u$ such that $\vec 1\cdot\vec u\neq 0$. The line $\vec v+\vec ut$ must intersect both planes. Solving for the intersections gives:

$$v_1=\vec v+(c_1-\vec 1\cdot\vec v)\frac{\vec u}{\vec 1\cdot\vec u},\ \ \ v_2=\vec v+(c_2-\vec 1\cdot\vec v)\frac{\vec u}{\vec 1\cdot\vec u}$$

Comment: Is there a way to add the constraint $\mathbb{v}_1 >= 0$, $\mathbb{v}_2>=0$ ?

Comment: By that do you mean that all the elements of $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ must be positive?

Comment: Yes,  I managed to do that by choosing $\mathbb{u}=\mathbb{v}$, as the elements of $\mathbb{v}$ are non-negative.

Comment: Choosing $\vec u=\vec 1$ will always suffice, but if you want the full set of possible choices of positive points $v_1$ and $v_2$, Things get a bit complicated.

Comment: Any solution is good, no need to have all the possible choices. Thank you.